# How to display tool tip always in line chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I have searched in google and was not able to find how to display tool tip in line chart. I am using angular-chart.js.

```
  $scope.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
  $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
  $scope.data = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
  $scope.onClick = function (points, evt) {
    console.log(points, evt);
  };
  $scope.datasetOverride = [{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }, { yAxisID: 'y-axis-2' }];
  $scope.options = {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y-axis-1',
          type: 'linear',
          display: true,
          position: 'left'
        },
        {
          id: 'y-axis-2',
          type: 'linear',
          display: true,
          position: 'right'
        }
      ]
    }
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
</canvas>
```

I am searching similar kind of [this](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/256), which displays percentage on the tool tip.

I have tried the below options.(found in the angular-js issues). But its not working.

```
var options = {
      scaleShowLabelBackdrop : true,
      scaleShowLabels : true,
      scaleBeginAtZero : true,
      scaleLabel : "Percent",
      multiTooltipTemplate: "10% achieved"
}
```

Comment: Cold you, please, provide fiddle? Tooltips are enabled by default. Maybe mousemove event from canvas dont fires correctly?
I had same issue, and reason was in css zoom property.

Comment: @Anton Stepanenkov On mouse-over tool tip is displayed. But I want the tool tip to display always irrespective of any event.